# How can I create my own GUID algorithm with smaller "global"?

Tags: guid

I have my own application with far more smaller "global" than our real global and I wanted shorter version of GUID. Now supposed I have my concrete number of IDs that I estimated to not ever exceed (for example 100 million IDs). How can I determine the number of random bits required to have the same property as GUID? (Globally unique, require no central authority to generate one) Using the normal GUID would be an overkill.

My "overkill" refers to this : I need the ID to be as easily typed/say/write down as possible and have somewhat astronomically low collision chance as GUID at the same time. I heard GUID can be assigned to every grain of sand on earth. My application is a game, each player get one ID generated, obviously my players is not as much as the amount of sand on earth.

It would be the best if player can say like "My ID is XXXX-XXXX". In that case, I would be not so sure if 8 characters of randomized hex is not enough or too much for 100 million players. (In reality I encode it to A-Z 0-9 instead of hex though) My game is not online restricted, so I would like each player to be able to obtain unique ID even when not online. (no server to check ID collisions)

GUID has been designed to be globally unique. But I don't know why that results in 128-bit sequence. Maybe they just choose the "very large" one that is a power of 2? I don't know what are they thinking when designing GUID to ensure that it will not clash. (They use world population times something? If that is the case I can too use 10 million times something.)

Comment: guid is unique because its based on mac address

Comment: @Lashane that is not 100% true.  v1 GUIDs use the MAC. v4 use pseudo-random numbers.

Comment: You need to study the "birthday paradox" the estimate how many bits you need for your purposes. But how is using the normal GUID "overkill"? What exactly is the prohibitive cost here?

Comment: @Joe which basically means "there are could be duplicates", so it is not global unique id, which betrays the idea

Comment: @Lashane: This was true for the MAC-based one as well - unless you only ever created one GUID per network adapter :) Besides, the MAC can be dynamically changed in some scenarios.

Comment: Why not just use a global counter for id, then?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError actually, original intent for mac address is _universally administered address is uniquely assigned to a device by its manufacturer_, but yeah - now you can have duplicates even with mac addresses

Comment: @Thilo My "overkill" refers to this : I need the ID to be as easily typed/say/write down as possible. My application is a game, and it would be the best if player can say like my ID is XXXX-XXXX. My game is not online restricted, so I would like each player to be able to obtain unique ID even when not online. (no server to check ID collisions)

Comment: @500-InternalServerError I want the property of not requiring some central authority to count and manage the ID that GUID has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have discussed with friend and came up with solution. This is how to decide the number of "characters" of my game ID.

A character would consist of 0-9 and A-Z instead of HEX, thats 36 kinds of characters. We took out 0 O 1 I so it would be printable to variety of fonts without confusion, that leaves 32 kind of characters.

Then if every characters will be pseudo-randomized, how many players can we safely have?

We used [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem)'s square approximation. The formula in that page indicate how many number of people necessary to have 50% chance of 2 people colliding. It is 22.99 people for birthday problem. (365 possible choices)

Now we substitute 32^No.of characters into the equation instead of 365. This is how many players that will cause 50% chance of 2 players having the same ID :

[image]

Finally, we agreed to choose 9-character ID so the game can be registered up to 6.9 million players before just 2 from all 6.9 million players will have the same ID (50% chance).

The game isn't even online-only! It only collide if that 2 players is still actively playing at the same time and decide to send score to the scoreboard in the same week because of weekly score reset. So the actual number that the game can hold would be somewhat higher than that. (The game will probably not having that many players.. it is just a small happy dream of every game startups. Well at least the computation was fun.)

It will probably looks like this for easier reading : 5XT-339-A67

Answer (score 2):

A 128-bit guid will generally perform well, because most compilers are smart enough to reduce operations on it to a pair of 64-bit operations (and on some CPUs, a single 128-bit extended operation).  Java and C#/VB.NET would likely have quite a bit more overhead than C++, but if you are using Java or C#/VB.NET, you've already accepted quite a bit more overhead, and a GUID won't add much to it.

However, if you really need smaller values, you could manually reduce GUIDs, by XOR-ing the upper 64 bits with the lower 64 bits (thereby preserving *some* of the uniqueness of the original) to create a compact 64-bit mostly-unique number.

You could reduce to 32-bit or 48-bit in a similar way, always a multiple of the size of the original GUID.  This has the advantage that you are starting out with a number that is intended to be unique across a very large set.  However, keep in mind that 100 million items require a fairly high number of bits to preserve a non-overlapping guarantee, so you may just be setting yourself up for a very difficult-to-find problem later on if you aren't careful.

A crude but probably equally effective approach is to use a cryptographically-secure random number generator and construct a number as large as you need (probably minimum 48-bit).  It is important not to do modulo operations on the results, or you could significantly reduce the uniqueness (due to the period of the random number generator).

I am assuming you cannot use a sequential id, although you may want to revisit that idea and see if there is a way to make a sequential id work.  For example, you could use a sequential id paired with a random seed number, guaranteeing uniqueness without requiring a large number, and allowing internal indexing operations and similar optimizations that are common with large data sets.